# How to check color/gray from printer job of Winspool API

Tags: printing

I've write a program to monitor printer by use winspool api by use
**FindFirstPrinterChangeNotification / FindNextChangeNotification** method.
I want to know is a job is gray or color print. I read api but not found solution.
How can i get color of job from PRINTER_NOTIFY_INFO_DATA ? or any where?

Answer (score 0):

You have to monitor JOB_NOTIFY_FIELD_DEVMODE field in PRINTER_NOTIFY_INFO_DATA structure. After FindNextPrinterChangeNotification call and job creation, notification arrives and you can retrive information about job color from notification data.

Example (not complete, but I hopes it help):

```
    ...
    PPRINTER_NOTIFY_INFO pNotification = NULL;
    ...
    FindNextPrinterChangeNotification(hNotification, &dwChange, &options, (LPVOID *) &pNotification);
    ...  
    PRINTER_NOTIFY_INFO_DATA jobData = pNotification->aData[notification_index];
    if (data.Field == JOB_NOTIFY_FIELD_DEVMODE)
    {
       DEVMODE *pDevMode = (DEVMODE *) jobData.NotifyData.Data.pBuf;
       int color = (pDevMode->dmFields & DM_COLOR ? pDevMode->dmColor : DMCOLOR_MONOCHROME);
    }
```